# Geometric interpretation of the nth root of a quaternion?

Tags: graphing-functions

For ordinary imaginary numbers, $(r,\theta)$ turns into $(\sqrt{r}, \theta /2)$ for the square root and it is similar for higher roots. Is there an analogous interpretation for roots of a quaternion?